# Jsf2 - Richfaces4 - Data scroller actionListener not called with datatable

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

To make it short, in a jsf page, I have 2 rich:dataTable.

The first one is loaded within the onLoad event of the page.

The second one is loaded when a row is clicked within the first.

Both tables have a rich:dataScroller.

Everything is working fine except that I don't find how to make working the actionListener of the dataScroller.

Schematically I have

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel>
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="table1">
        <rich:dataTable>
            <f:facet name="header">
            </f:facet>
            <rich:column>
            </rich:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <rich:dataScroller reRender="table1,table2" page="1" actionListener="#{mybean.ac}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </rich:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="table2">
        <rich:dataTable rendered="#{myBean.rowSelected != null}">
            <f:facet name="header">
            </f:facet>      
            <rich:column>
            </rich:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <rich:dataScroller reRender="table1" page="1" />
            </f:facet>
        </rich:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
</rich:collapsiblePanel>
```

In my bean I have

```
Long rowSelected;

public void ac()
{
rowSelected = null;
System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}
```

But nothing to do, never succeeded to make it work.

I also tried without any différence

```
public void ac(ActionEvent ae)    -  using javax.faces.event.ActionEvent
```

and

```
action="#{mybean.ac}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<rich:dataScroller>` has neither `action` nor `actionListener` attributes. If you're using RichFaces 4.3 you can use `scrollListener`. See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.5.Final/vdldoc/rich/dataScroller.html).

Comment: Rrr, two hours lost because I was looking in the richfaces 3 documentation !  Ok, thanks, now it's working with scrollListener.  But ... (see edited question) the table2 dataTable remains rendered.  (The first time I call the page, it's good, it's not rendered).

Comment: <rich:dataScroller> has neither action nor actionListener attributes? then why can I see both in the docs? And it's richfaces 3.3.x https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/datascroller.html

Comment: @WajihAziza because you're looking at the docs for RichFaces 3. The question (and my answer) was dealing with RichFaces 4.